# Keyboard accessory view hiding text

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have the following problem: I have a standard UITextView which I resize once the keyboard pops up. I also have another view which I animate into view (not the standard accessory view attached to the keyboard). The problem is that I do not want text to be hidden by this view. This is what happens when I reach the last line (orange view = my custom accessory view):

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to have an automatic scroll should that happen. But I have no clue how to achieve this if I am in the **last line** of the UITextView. Also, scrollToVisible doesn't work in this context and I don't know if I'd get anywhere with contentInset.

Any suggestions would be welcome! Thanks.

**EDIT**

I suppose I would need some kind of mechanism which would allow to

1. make the textview only expand to the line right above the accessory view if I was entering something on the LAST LINE
2. have the textview expand to the keyboard if I was not editing the LINE DIRECTLY ABOVE the KEYBOARD.

Does that make sense? What I need is the opposite of contentInset, I suppose.

I simply don't want to resize the textView to just above the accessory view as it takes away screen space to display text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution- sorry, I guess it was obvious, but it took me the whole day to figure it out:

```
textOfPage.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);
```

This will offset my UITextView so that the last line is never hidden. The 100 is in pixels and can be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is resize the textview in the `textViewShouldBeginEditing` method to fit above the keyboard and the newly added accessory view, and then resize it back to full screen when the keyboard is dismissed in `textViewShouldEndEditing`

Comment: Actually, how about getting the last line of the text and finding its width with textViewDidChangeSelection and if it's wider than a certain number you automatically append a newline character to the text?

Comment: As for your first suggestion, I'm afraid that it won't help much as I want to have the extra space if there is more text. Imagine that you wanted to edit line 25 and there are more lines coming after (e.g. lines 26,27,28). What you suggested would make my UITextView smaller so that lines 26,27,28etc. would not be shown if I were to edit line 25.

Comment: As for your second suggestion, I don't really want to append a newline character if the user doesn't want to have this input. All I want is to somehow clip the view that is editable but still show the rest (as in the figure above).

Comment: Sorry Radu, just figured it out myself. I need to use textOfPage.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0); ... Thanks for your help, though!